# Show newline characters in neovim

Tags: vimrc, neovim

In `vi`/`vim` I can throw `set list` in my `.vimrc` file to show newline characters as `$` which is very useful for my development needs.

Though the same command in `neovim` shows only `-` for trailing spaces while newlines are still invisible.

Is there any way to show newline characters in `neovim` as it's in `vi`/`vim`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so after looking up a documentation and a good portion of time figuring out how to make it work properly I found the solution.

I run `help 'list'` from inside `neovim` and found out that by default newline characters are not shown in `neovim`s `list` mode. To show them (as well as other characters you want) the following command can be used:

`set list listchars=tab:>\ ,trail:-,eol:$`

Notice the backslash `\` above as it's necessary to add it to include spaces in a particular character representation (like `tab` character that would be shown as `>` plus spaces).

For additional information you can read docs with `help 'listchars'` from inside `neovim`.

Comment: Well, yeah, if you use `set list` you probably should customise `listchars`.  Vim and Neovim have some differences in the initialisation files they load and that is what likely cause the difference.  Using a proper definition in vimrc & viminit should make it consistent and avoid things set by the distribution or installer.